# Style preference in setters: Class::member = value or this->member = value?

Tags: c++, setter

This seems like a really simple question, but I've been unable to find any opinions on it. When writing setters in C++, what is the difference between

```
void ClassName::set_member( type value ) {
    ClassName::member = value;
}
```

and

```
void ClassName::set_member( type value ) {
    this->member = value;
}
```

CLion generates the first version, so I suspect it has some advantage, but I don't see what that would be.

Comment: I would go with `member = value;` and save some typing.

Comment: Isn't the first version setting a static member while the second sets an instance member?

Comment: @super, good point, that's what I usually do. CLion creates the methods with the same parameter name as the class, so my mind was bent to using a qualifier.

Comment: @fstam This seems syntatically sensible, however, the code is generated for, and works fine with, non-static members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The difference is purely syntactic.** Both versions have exactly the same effect. It doesn’t even matter whether `member` is static or non-static. Only from inside a static member function you cannot use the `this->` version because there is no object and thus no `this`.

Because it feels really weird it bears repeating: Even if `member` is a *static* member variable `this->member = value;` is valid and does the right thing.

As for preferring one style over the other: like all stylistic choices that’s highly subjective. A clear answer isn’t really possible. But there are indictators of what the C++ community prefers in general. You might look at:

- open source C++ code on GitHub etc., or your standard library implementation
- code snippets on presentation slides from major conferences like CppCon, Meeting C++, C++ Now etc.
- major C++ books, e.g. Stroustroup’s *The C++ Programming Language* or Scott Meyers’ *Effective C++* series

Considering all that I’m confident to say that the prevalent style is none of your two, but:

```
member = value;
```

On a purely personal note: For non-static members the `ClassName::` version feels unfamiliar to an extent that I would call it out in a code review. `this->` usually makes me wonder “Was this written by a Java programmer?”, but overall – especially if it’s used consistently – it’s an ok style, although unusual; and in some special template metaprogramming cicumstances it’s even mandatory.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer largely mirrors my suspicions (in fact, the question came up because I _did_ call this syntax out in a code review! It's a university project and none of us are experts) .